# Flink client does not set environment variables

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink

I am trying to submit a Flink job to a Kubernetes cluster (session mode) using the Flink client.

The problem is when I try to read environment variables in my java code using `Stringvalue=System.getenv(name)` it returns null.

I configured my environment variables in the
jobmanager pod. However when I use the jobmanager UI to submit the job my variables are set correctly.

So is there any solutions to get my environment variables values when using Flink client?

Answer (score 0):

Found this, maybe it will help you: [How to inject many properties into Flink Jobs](https://ververica.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015024119-How-to-inject-many-properties-into-Flink-Jobs-running-on-Ververica-Platform), **Environment Variables** section.

```
#setting env vars in pod
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      kubernetes:
        pods:
          envVars:
            - name: envvar1
              value: value1
            - name: envvar2
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  key: envvar2
                  name: jobprops
            - name: envvar3
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: password
                  name: jobsecret
```

> Environment variable values can be set directly in YAML (`envvar1`),
> from a Kubernetes ConfigMap (`envvar2`), or from a Kubernetes Secret
> (`envvar3`). The referenced ConfigMap and Kubernetes Secrets must
> reside in the same Kubernetes namespace as your deployment.
>
> As with any other Java program, values of environment variables can be
> retrieved via the Java class [System](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html):

```
Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
String envvar1 = env.get("envvar1");
String envvar2 = env.get("envvar2");
String envvar3 = env.get("envvar3");
```

Comment: thanks for your response , i just want to say that i have already configured my environments variables in a configmap but the problem is when i use flink client (flink run -m jobmgr myjarfile) from my host machine ubuntu to submit the job to k8S cluster running on minikube  my job is executed on the client side (my local machine) so it doesn't use the env variables in my pod. i didn't have any problem when using the jobManager UI to submit the job.